# Twitch Player : Getting error - "Whoops! This embed is misconfigured" while playing video from twitch player

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, twitch

I am using Twitch player library for playing video but getting error on load. Have anyone idea what changes have come in June 2020 to make it functional ?

class TwitchVideoPlayerViewController: TwitchPlayerViewController {

```
/// `videosArray` holds the videos that will be cycled through.
private static let videosArray = ["v708953783", "v70878990"]
/// `nextStreamIndex` holds the index of the video that should be cycled to next.
private var nextVideoIndex = 0


@IBAction func nextButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    let videoToPlay = TwitchVideoPlayerViewController.videosArray[nextVideoIndex]
    nextVideoIndex = (nextVideoIndex + 1) % TwitchVideoPlayerViewController.videosArray.count
    twitchPlayer.setVideo(to: videoToPlay, timestamp: 0)
    
}
```

}

Link:- [https://github.com/Chris-Perkins/TwitchPlayer[![enter](https://github.com/Chris-Perkins/TwitchPlayer%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObiR5.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObiR5.png)